# $.ajax, async:false, and IE 9+

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a .NET web app that heavily uses jQuery. Within a particular page, I am using several `$.ajax` calls where I have set async to false. I know there is a lot of data being retrieved by the ajax calls, and I realize that using `$.ajax` synchronously is dicey. I certainly can refactor using async calls; thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Nothing unusual in the calls:

```
var XX = $.ajax({
    url: 'EH/SaveData.ashx',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: jsonString,
    async: false,
    cache: false
}).responseText;
```

Everything works fine in VS2010, on all browsers. However on our dev IIS server, IE9 and IE10 take several minutes to display while IE8, Chrome, and FF are fine. What changed in IE9 that could cause such radical differences in performance?

OK. Guys. I've refactored code to remove synchronous calls via $.ajax but the issues with IE remain. I have access to IIS7 config settings. Anybody have a guess or 3?

Comment: What the heck is that? `async: false`

Comment: probably you should start with async requests....

Comment: suggestion: Take your own advice and refactor to async

Comment: The docs say it all: The first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous," meaning that the operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion is not guaranteed. The async option to $.ajax() defaults to true, indicating that code execution can continue after the request is made. Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive.

Comment: I kinda doubt the fact that it's sync has anything to do with how long it's taking to complete the request in relation to other browsers.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I was just being ironic.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You're right. Hahaha

Comment: You need to do a little more debugging on your end. What exactly is this request returning? What kind of data is it? if you make the request manually by creating a <form> and submitting it, does it take just as long? these tests will tell you whether or not this is a server/network issue or a code/browser issue.

Comment: well, the fact that current code works well in the IDE on all browsers, and on IIS on all but IE9+ tells me that something might have changed in IE after 8 that is affecting the result. And that even in IE9+, it eventually returns the correct data... OK. Refactor. Grrr...

Comment: Right... but it could be something completely unrelated to async: false, that's why i'm asking you to debug it further. For example, maybe you have a massive xml doc and those versions of IE are just inefficient at parsing some aspect of it.

Comment: Could be, Kevin. Will do some more digging... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a call to update an empty updatePanel in the Master Page via __doPostback("updatePanelID") in a javascript function (to keep the session alive). I guess the viewstate changed, but I'm not sure specifically what IE detected that other browsers ignored. Maybe others have thoughts...